# WPF ScrollViewer set ScrollableHeight

Tags: wpf, scrollviewer, customizing

I have a user control which paints content in `OnRender`. The `Height` of that control grows by and by.

I added this control to a `ScrollViewer`. The control does only repaint the currently visible area (`viewport`) (+/- a view lines for smoother scrolling).
Everything works fine so far...

But since the control usualy grows up to a few hundred thousands of pixels I want to keep the `Height` of my control as small as possible and provide a different `Height` value to bind to the `ScrollableHeight` of the `ScrollViewer` (same goes for `VerticalOffset`). But there is no setter for `ScrollableHeight`. It binds automatically to the Height of my Control. Neither can I override Height.

How can I customize my `ScrollViewer` (or `VerticalScrollbar`) to keep the real `Height` of my control small?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did something like this in the past. What you need to do is to write your own layout [Panel](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms754152.aspx#Panels_custom_panel_elements) and implement the [IScrollInfo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.primitives.iscrollinfo.aspx) in it. The interface looks big, but most of it is just calling one of the main set methods. The layouter needs to set some of the `IScrollInfo` properties, like `ExtentHeight`, `Offset` etc. and these are your way to customize how the `ScrollViewer` will calculate the scroll position and the scrollable area for your "virtual" canvas size. For implementing the `IScrollInfo` i used [this](http://tech.pro/tutorial/907/wpf-tutorial-implementing-iscrollinfo) tutorial as a guidance.